# CSV read write in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have this CSV with me called **task2.csv**. The header is :**Item** and **Description**. 
I am trying to add `" i", " ink"` to this csv using following csv python script. but it is adding to a wrong column and modify the last field.
Please help me make my script start from a fresh new row.

### Things I tried:

- save the csv with pointer to the new row
- wrote twice ( the second time write function was called it worked correctly. the first write still modifies the last row but second write writes to the new row.
- checked stack overflow and modified the according to few suggestions ( Use dictReader and dictWriter) still did not work

### My Code:

```
import csv

def readCsv(file):
    dict = {}
    with open(file) as csvdata:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvdata)
        for row in csvReader:
            print row['item'], row['description']

def writeCsv(file, field):
    fieldnames = ['item', 'description']
    with open(file, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow({'item': 'i', 'description': 'ink'})

writeCsv("task2.csv", "a")
readCsv("task2.csv")
```

**ORGINAL CSV:**

[image]

**MODIFIED CSV:**

[image]

Comment: why have you tagged both `python-2.7` and `python-3.x`?

Comment: because it wont let me post my question unless I find another tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue.

**Reason :** Your CSV last row is not complete ; The last line is **not** ended with 'new line` character i.e \n

and to be on safer side chanage `writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)` to

> `writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, 
>   lineterminator="\n")`

Open csv in notepad, press **Enter** after `hati` and **Save**

Run the program then, it should fix the issue.